# Interpolating raster from points from a vertical datum conversion point feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation

I have a shapefile with points distributed uniformly representing the difference between two vertical datums. These are spaced in 4 corners of a 2950 x 3700 square.

I would like to create a continuous raster at a lower resolution by interpolating the nearest point values, so I can convert between datums more accurately.

What would be the best raster interpolation tool for this job and what parameters should I use?

Comment: Do want to keep the same spacing in the raster or interpolate to a smaller resolution raster?

Comment: I want to interpolate to a smaller raster resolution.